# php replace images with divs

Tags: php

below is the markup im pulling from my database table. basically i want to replace the image

```
<img src="http://newvision.co.ug/IM/logo_white_big.gif" width="80" style="background-color:white;padding:1px">
```

to

```
<div style='background:url(http://newvision.co.ug/IM/logo_white_big.gif) center center no-repeat;width:40px;height:40px'></div>
```

I dnt wanna use regular expressions just an htmlparser that ships with php

```
  <table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><a href="http://newvision.co.ug/PA/8/13/748484" target=
    "_blank"><img src="http://newvision.co.ug/IM/logo_white_big.gif" width="80"
    style="background-color:white;padding:1px" /></a></td>

    <td valign="top">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><b><a target="_blank" href=
            "http://newvision.co.ug/PA/8/13/748484" style="font-size:9pt">The New
            Vision Online : Holland withholds sh10b over CHOGM</a></b></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><a href="http://newvision.co.ug/PA/8/13/748484" style=
            "font-size:8pt;color&lt;img src=&quot;smilies/worry.gif&quot; alt=&quot;worry&quot; /&gt;ilver"
            target="_blank">http://newvision.co.ug/PA/8/13/748484</a></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal">The New Vision
            is Uganda's leading daily newspaper.</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parser that ships with PHP, so use [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), a way of manipulating the DOM in a JQuery like manner instead. This will allow you to use selectors to easily swap out chunks of HTML.

Comment: how about using $doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML

Comment: Yup, you can do that, but PHPQuery will save you a whole lot of pain searching through the DOM.

Comment: well, thats about how far i know using DOMDocument(). anyone who can use domobject to answer the question.

Comment: @Sir Lojik: phpQuery uses `DOMDocument` internally. It is simply a wrapper to make your life simpler. Don't dismiss it so quickly and take a look.